# Highcharts Treemap Custom Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am building treemap using Highcharts Treemap in which I have sector categories. Categories are displayed properly but I want the width of category to be 100%(IT, Chemical etc in JSFiddle). Currently I can only position it left/right/centre.

`JSFiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/gvb70cwj/1/`

Attaching a screenshot of expected output(check Banks, Automobiles etc width).
[image]

Comment: You can try to access this element in the object and give it an atrr as in this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0zdtc1La/). If you want style CSS you need to use `styledMode: true`, [doc](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, you can pass custom html to that element.

`Example : https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tq9n5fbk/`